# How to make sublime text 3 menu bar darker?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3, material-design

I am using Material theme in sublime text3 and it's perfect except the menu bar as it is white. How can I change it to dark color?
[check my screenshot for brief understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NtCv.png)

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki thanks for your information, I will close this question and ask in super user